# R: Changing the size of a heatmap.2 rowname column

Tags: r, heatmap, gplots

I used the following code:

```
library("gplots")
heatmap.2(assay(vsd)[ens_union,], trace = "none", density.info = "none")
```

To produce the following heatmap:

[image: heatmap.2: row labels cut-off]

As you can see, the row labels have been cut-off (the first one should, for instance, be `ENSMUSG00000000088`, but only `ENSMUSG0` is displayed). How can I re-size the plot to include the whole labels?

Comment: Looking at the documentation `?gplots::heatmap.2`, it appears that you can pass arguments to `?par` directly. `mai= c(b, l, t, r)` controls the image margins

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the `margins` argument

```
library("gplots")

# generate some example data
data <- as.matrix(mtcars)

# make ridiculously long names
long.names     <- paste("ENSMUSG000000000", rownames(mtcars))
rownames(data) <- long.names

# GO!
heatmap.2(data, trace = "none", density.info = "none", 
          margins = c(8, 16))
```

Don't forget you can also change the font size if you like with `cexRow`